# Copying data from FormControl menu to two seperate worksheet tabs

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code, which when run by itself, works perfectly and does what it supposed to do.

```
Public Sub TotalsUpdated()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Rate Calc")

Dim TotalCtnsCFSAir As String
Dim TotalPalletsCFSAir As String
Dim TotalWeightCFSAir As String
Dim TotalCBMCFSAir As String

TotalCtnsCFSAir = TotalCtnsAir.Text
TotalPalletsCFSAir = TotalPalletsAir.Text
TotalWeightCFSAir = TotalWeightAir.Text
TotalCBMCFSAir = TotalCBMAir.Text

ws.Range("C12").Value = TotalCtnsCFSAir
ws.Range("C9").Value = TotalWeightCFSAir
ws.Range("C10").Value = TotalCBMCFSAir
ws.Range("C11").Value = TotalPalletsCFSAir
Set ws = Nothing: Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have tried the below code by calling this routine but it fails to copy the data over, no error messages, just no data copied, but it works fine if I run the sub by itself using the F5 key in editor screen.

Both reside in the same Forms location.

However, when trying to call this routine from within another sub, in the same 'FORMS' folder it fails, where am I going wrong?

```
Public Sub SaveButtonAir_Click()

'Declare variables
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cb7Air As ComboBox
Dim cb8Air As ComboBox
Dim cb93Air As ComboBox
Dim cb10Air As ComboBox
Dim cb11Air As ComboBox
Dim cb12Air As ComboBox
Dim CartonstrText1Air As String
Dim CartonstrText2Air As String
Dim CartonstrText3Air As String
Dim CartonstrText4Air As String
Dim CartonstrText5Air As String
Dim CartonstrText6Air As String
Dim WeightstrText1Air As String
Dim WeightstrText2Air As String
Dim WeightstrText3Air As String
Dim WeightstrText4Air As String
Dim WeightstrText5Air As String
Dim WeightstrText6Air As String
Dim CBMstrText1Air As String
Dim CBMstrText2Air As String
Dim CBMstrText3Air As String
Dim CBMstrText4Air As String
Dim CBMstrText5Air As String
Dim CBMstrText6Air As String

'Get the text from the textbox
' Set variables
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("FormsControl Sheet")
Set cb7Air = Me.CFSCollectionAir1
Set cb8Air = Me.CFSCollectionAir2
Set cb9Air = Me.CFSCollectionAir3
Set cb10Air = Me.CFSCollectionAir4
Set cb11Air = Me.CFSCollectionAir5
Set cb12Air = Me.CFSCollectionAir6
CartonstrText1Air = Carton1Air.Text
CartonstrText2Air = Carton2Air.Text
CartonstrText3Air = Carton3Air.Text
CartonstrText4Air = Carton4Air.Text
CartonstrText5Air = Carton5Air.Text
CartonstrText6Air = Carton6Air.Text
PalletstrText1Air = Pallet1Air.Text
PalletstrText2Air = Pallet2Air.Text
PalletstrText3Air = Pallet3Air.Text
PalletstrText4Air = Pallet4Air.Text
PalletstrText5Air = Pallet5Air.Text
PalletstrText6Air = Pallet6Air.Text
WeightstrText1Air = Weight1Air.Text
WeightstrText2Air = Weight2Air.Text
WeightstrText3Air = Weight3Air.Text
WeightstrText4Air = Weight4Air.Text
WeightstrText5Air = Weight5Air.Text
WeightstrText6Air = Weight6Air.Text
CBMstrText1Air = CBM1Air.Text
CBMstrText2Air = CBM2Air.Text
CBMstrText3Air = CBM3Air.Text
CBMstrText4Air = CBM4Air.Text
CBMstrText5Air = CBM5Air.Text
CBMstrText6Air = CBM6Air.Text

'Set the destination worksheet
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = Worksheets("FormsControl Sheet")

'Copy the text to cells in Sheet FormsControl Sheet

ws.Range("B25").Value = cb7Air.Value
ws.Range("B27").Value = cb8Air.Value
ws.Range("B29").Value = cb9Air.Value
ws.Range("B31").Value = cb10Air.Value
ws.Range("B33").Value = cb11Air.Value
ws.Range("B35").Value = cb12Air.Value
ws.Range("D25").Value = CartonstrText1Air
ws.Range("D27").Value = CartonstrText2Air
ws.Range("D29").Value = CartonstrText3Air
ws.Range("D31").Value = CartonstrText4Air
ws.Range("D33").Value = CartonstrText5Air
ws.Range("D35").Value = CartonstrText6Air
ws.Range("F25").Value = PalletstrText1Air
ws.Range("F27").Value = PalletstrText2Air
ws.Range("F29").Value = PalletstrText3Air
ws.Range("F31").Value = PalletstrText4Air
ws.Range("F33").Value = PalletstrText5Air
ws.Range("F35").Value = PalletstrText6Air
ws.Range("H25").Value = WeightstrText1Air
ws.Range("H27").Value = WeightstrText2Air
ws.Range("H29").Value = WeightstrText3Air
ws.Range("H31").Value = WeightstrText4Air
ws.Range("H33").Value = WeightstrText5Air
ws.Range("H35").Value = WeightstrText6Air
ws.Range("J25").Value = CBMstrText1Air
ws.Range("J27").Value = CBMstrText2Air
ws.Range("J29").Value = CBMstrText3Air
ws.Range("J31").Value = CBMstrText4Air
ws.Range("J33").Value = CBMstrText5Air
ws.Range("J35").Value = CBMstrText6Air
Call TotalsUpdated
Set ws = Nothing: Set wb = Nothing
'Unload the userform
CFSCollectionAir.Hide
'Unload CFSCollectionAir
End Sub
 
Public Sub Carton1Air_Change()
    UpdateCtnsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Carton2Air_Change()
    UpdateCtnsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Carton3Air_Change()
    UpdateCtnsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Carton4Air_Change()
    UpdateCtnsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Carton5Air_Change()
    UpdateCtnsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Carton6Air_Change()
    UpdateCtnsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateCtnsTotalAir()
    'Get the values of the 6 textboxes
    Dim TextBox25Value As Double
    Dim TextBox26Value As Double
    Dim TextBox27Value As Double
    Dim TextBox28Value As Double
    Dim TextBox29Value As Double
    Dim TextBox30Value As Double

    TextBox25Value = Val(Carton1Air.Text)
    TextBox26Value = Val(Carton2Air.Text)
    TextBox27Value = Val(Carton3Air.Text)
    TextBox28Value = Val(Carton4Air.Text)
    TextBox29Value = Val(Carton5Air.Text)
    TextBox30Value = Val(Carton6Air.Text)
       
    'Calculate the total
    Dim Total As Double
    Total = TextBox25Value + TextBox26Value + TextBox27Value + TextBox28Value + TextBox29Value + TextBox30Value

    'Display the total in the total textbox
    TotalCtnsAir.Text = Format(Total, "0")
End Sub

Public Sub Pallet1Air_Change()
UpdatePalletsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Pallet2Air_Change()
UpdatePalletsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Pallet3Air_Change()
UpdatePalletsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Pallet4Air_Change()
UpdatePalletsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Pallet5Air_Change()
UpdatePalletsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Pallet6Air_Change()
UpdatePalletsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub UpdatePalletsTotalAir()
'Get the values of the 6 textboxes
    Dim TextBox31Value As Double
    Dim TextBox32Value As Double
    Dim TextBox33Value As Double
    Dim TextBox34Value As Double
    Dim TextBox35Value As Double
    Dim TextBox36Value As Double

    TextBox31Value = Val(Pallet1Air.Text)
    TextBox32Value = Val(Pallet2Air.Text)
    TextBox33Value = Val(Pallet3Air.Text)
    TextBox34Value = Val(Pallet4Air.Text)
    TextBox35Value = Val(Pallet5Air.Text)
    TextBox36Value = Val(Pallet6Air.Text)

    'Calculate the total
    Dim Total As Double
    Total = TextBox31Value + TextBox32Value + TextBox33Value + TextBox34Value + TextBox35Value + TextBox36Value

    'Display the total in the total textbox
    TotalPalletsAir.Text = Format(Total, "0")
End Sub

Public Sub Weight1Air_Change()
    UpdateWeightsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Weight2Air_Change()
    UpdateWeightsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Weight3Air_Change()
    UpdateWeightsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Weight4Air_Change()
    UpdateWeightsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Weight5Air_Change()
    UpdateWeightsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub Weight6Air_Change()
    UpdateWeightsTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateWeightsTotalAir()
    'Get the values of the 6 textboxes
    Dim TextBox37Value As Double
    Dim TextBox38Value As Double
    Dim TextBox39Value As Double
    Dim TextBox40Value As Double
    Dim TextBox41Value As Double
    Dim TextBox42Value As Double

    TextBox37Value = Val(Weight1Air.Text)
    TextBox38Value = Val(Weight2Air.Text)
    TextBox39Value = Val(Weight3Air.Text)
    TextBox40Value = Val(Weight4Air.Text)
    TextBox41Value = Val(Weight5Air.Text)
    TextBox42Value = Val(Weight6Air.Text)

    'Calculate the total
    Dim Total As Double
    Total = TextBox37Value + TextBox38Value + TextBox39Value + TextBox40Value + TextBox41Value + TextBox42Value

    'Display the total in the total textbox
    TotalWeightAir.Text = Format(Total, "0")

End Sub

Public Sub CBM1Air_Change()
    UpdateCBMTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub CBM2Air_Change()
    UpdateCBMTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub CBM3Air_Change()
    UpdateCBMTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub CBM4Air_Change()
    UpdateCBMTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub CBM5Air_Change()
    UpdateCBMTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub CBM6Air_Change()
    UpdateCBMTotalAir
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateCBMTotalAir()
    'Get the values of the 6 textboxes
    Dim TextBox43Value As Double
    Dim TextBox44Value As Double
    Dim TextBox45Value As Double
    Dim TextBox46Value As Double
    Dim TextBox47Value As Double
    Dim TextBox48Value As Double

    TextBox43Value = Val(CBM1Air.Text)
    TextBox44Value = Val(CBM2Air.Text)
    TextBox45Value = Val(CBM3Air.Text)
    TextBox46Value = Val(CBM4Air.Text)
    TextBox47Value = Val(CBM5Air.Text)
    TextBox48Value = Val(CBM6Air.Text)

    'Calculate the total
    Dim Total As Double
    Total = TextBox43Value + TextBox44Value + TextBox45Value + TextBox46Value + TextBox47Value + TextBox48Value

    'Display the total in the total textbox
    TotalCBMAir.Text = Format(Total, "0.00")
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your code located in a code module or a userform?  (which code is where?)

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `TotalsUpdated` and step through it to see what's going on.  The call to that method looks OK...

Comment: Hi Peter, 
The Sub TotalsUpdated() ia located in the CFSCollectionAir Forms module ie its in the same module as the Sub SaveButtonAir_Click()

Comment: Hi Tim,
Im not sure what you mean (I am noob when it comes to VBA so please bear with me here), I have used F8 to step through and nothing is being flagged as incorrect.